# What does "Grant Running" mean?

Tags: meaning

Googled these two words together, but don't find much. First time heard it.(an ESL student)

Does it mean the grant has already been secured, or has other meaning?

added, File title as "Computer Program Grant Running Meeting Notes"

Comment: Including the context that you came across it might help.

Comment: Absent some more context it's gibberish

Comment: @HotLicks It's not, if you've heard of "running notes"

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-: But this parses as "notes" on a "running meeting", not "running notes"

Comment: @BenVoigt My Google Doc file called "running meeting notes" is running notes from a recurring meeting. I think this is the same as what Barmar has written, if you disagree, pelase do leave an answer.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-: your "recurring meeting" likely also fits the definition of a "running meeting"

Comment: First name: Grant. Last name: Running.

Comment: Given the way scientific research is going, if there aren't grantrunners (analogous to Hollywood showrunners) today, there soon will be!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

"grant running" is not a phrase, you're not parsing it correctly.

The two phrases are "computer program grant" and "running meeting notes".

"Computer program grant" is a grant that supports computer programs.

"Running meeting notes" are meeting notes (i.e. minutes of the meetings) that are being produced continuously. The meetings are still going on, and these are the cumulative notes so far, as opposed to the final minutes when all the meetings are done.

So the entire thing means

> Ongoing minutes of the meetings about the computer program grant.

Comment: It could conceivably also be the phrases "Computer Program Grant Running" and "Meeting Notes". As in, meeting notes about running the grant related to the computer program. However, I do think your parsing is more likely.

Comment: Running meeting notes could also be notes about a whole series of meetings that are kept in one document, updated after each meeting. Or if your meeting spans several days, it could be updated daily or something. It doesn't need to be continuously, but it should have some variety of multiple updates.

Comment: @user3067860 That's essentially the same, just a matter of degree.

Comment: Grant could also be the name of the author of notes about a computer program.

Comment: @WBT it could even be an acronym for the name of the program (regardless of case).  I've seen worse